# C# Running an automated VBScript over session rather than locally

Tags: c#, session, vbscript, process, citrix

I am making an application for clients to use when they are facing issues with the server or our internal system, and need to retrieve the name of the current (Citrix) server - **The app is running locally on the client's desktop, but I am saving the script to a network folder.**

I have the following code in my app, which generates a VBSscript file for the use of grabbing the current server name:

```
        string myAppData = @"H:\My Documents\";
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(myAppData + "\\GetServ.vbs", false);

        string lines = "Dim objFSO, objNetwork, strServer, userAppData, folder, objFile, objShell \n" +
            "Set objShell = CreateObject(\"WScript.Shell\") \n" +
            "Set objFSO = CreateObject(\"Scripting.FileSystemObject\") \n" +
            "Set objNetwork = CreateObject(\"WScript.Network\") \n" +
            "strServer = objNetwork.ComputerName \n" +
            "userAppData = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings(\"%APPDATA%\") \n" +
            "folder = objFSO.GetFolder(userAppData) \n" +
            "outfile =\"" + myAppData + "\" & strServer & \".txt\" \n" +
            "Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(outfile, True) \n" +
            "MsgBox(strServer) \n";

        tw.Write(lines);
        tw.Close();
```

Once the script has been created, we execute the script using Process.Start():

```
        Process runScript = new Process();
        runScript.StartInfo.FileName = @"cscript";
        runScript.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = myAppData;
        runScript.StartInfo.Arguments = "//B //Nologo GetServ.vbs";
        runScript.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; //prevent console window from popping up
        runScript.Start();
        runScript.WaitForExit(); 
        runScript.Close();
```

The issue I am seeing, is that when the app runs the script, using runScript.Start(), it is being run as if the script is saved locally (it retrieves the PC name rather than the server name.

However, when I double-click on the script myself after it was created, it retrieves the (correct) server name, as though it is being run over the Citrix session.

**Is there a way to run the script in the context of the Citrix session programmatically?**